# What is the iPhone simulator IP address?

Tags: iphone, network-programming

I have been looking for the answer to this question for some time. I am doing network programming for the iPhone and it is necessary for me to use the IP address of the device. This isn't a problem on the physical device as it has its own IP address on the network. However I was wondering what was the case with it on the simulator. Does it get assigned an IP address to be used?

Comment: Is it not possible to check your router? My netgear gives me a list of attached devices, should be a process of elimination. Alternatively is there not an option in the settings, perhaps in about that would give you the answer?

Answer (score 14):

The ip address of the machine you are running it on

Comment: The iPhone simulator doesn't have its own network interface. All the network API's simply route network calls through to the system's network API. This is one of the main reasons why testing network related code shouldn't be done on the simulator.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for that. That could make this a bit more difficult to test unfortunately :(

Comment: If you're running a server on your machine, then you can contact your server from within your app on the simulator using 127.0.0.1 - very useful!

Answer (score 2):

should be 127.0.0.1

Comment: Simple, but actually a great answer. I had no idea. If you are running a server on your local, you can contact the server using 127.0.0.1 from the simulator. This whole time I had been uploading server code to a remote server every time to test minor changes when I was on networks that didn't allow devices to contact one another (using a real device).